# while loop not working C++

Tags: c++, while-loop, scanf

This is my code:

```
signed int x;
while (!(scanf("%d", &x) == 42)) {
std::cout << x << std::endl; }
return 0;
```

It should print any number inputted by the user except 42. if the user inputs 42, it should ignore it or exit, but it's not working. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: while ((scanf("%d", &x) > 0 && x != 42)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are testing the returning of the `scanf` function, when you should test the value read `x`.

Do like this:

```
signed int x;
while (scanf("%d", &x) > 0 && x != 42) {
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
return 0;
```

It will first read the user input, if it's a number and it is not 42 it will print. The loop will remain until the user enter an invalid input (say a letter) or the number 42.

Comment: This still prints 42. `#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
 
int main() {
signed int x;
do { scanf("%d", &x);
std::cout << x << std::endl; } 
while (x != 42);
return 0; }`

Comment: that's true.. you can add a condition to not print it or there's a way to improve the while loop, which would be best, let me correct

Answer (score 2):

`scanf` doesn't return what you think it returns, [look it up](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/).

Answer (score 2):

Read the `scanf`documentation : the value is not returned, it's inside the `x` variable